# Https connection with proxy on Python 2.6.9

Tags: python, url, https, proxy, download

I am working on python 2.6.9 and new to python. Trying to download a file over https with proxy.

Tried many codes urllib, urllib2, httpsconnection but none of them are working.

I will appreciate any help or any link to guide me through this.

Upgrading to new version is not an option

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Could you please include your code sample? What was the exact error?

Comment: So like I followed below link https:/code.activestate.com/recipes/456195-urrlib2-opener-for-ssl-proxy-connect-method/    but getting urllib2.URLError: Errno 11004 getaddrinfo falied